# KendoUI DataSource binding to MVVM grid in durandal (using hottowel template) doesn't seem to work

Tags: kendo-ui, durandal, hottowel, jaydata

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 hottowel template with updated durandal and jquery nuget packages...

Here is my code:
Durandal main.js:

```
require.config({
    paths: { "text": "durandal/amd/text" }
});

define(['durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'durandal/viewModelBinder', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/logger'],
    function (app, viewLocator, viewModelBinder, system, router, logger) {

    // Enable debug message to show in the console 
    system.debug(true);

    app.start().then(function () {
        toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';
        toastr.options.backgroundpositionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';

        router.handleInvalidRoute = function (route, params) {
            logger.logError('No Route Found', route, 'main', true);
        };

        // When finding a viewmodel module, replace the viewmodel string 
        // with view to find it partner view.
        router.useConvention();
        viewLocator.useConvention();

        // Adapt to touch devices
        app.adaptToDevice();

        kendo.ns = "kendo-";
        viewModelBinder.beforeBind = function (obj, view) {
            kendo.bind(view, obj.viewModel || obj);
        };
        //Show the app by setting the root view model for our application.
        app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
    });
});
```

Durandal viewmodel:

```
define(['services/datacontext', 'durandal/plugins/router'],
    function (datacontext, router) {


        var activate = function () {
            //yes yes - I will separate this out to a datacontext - it is here for debugging simplicity
            var service = $data.initService("https://open.jaystack.net/c72e6c4b-27ba-49bb-9321-e167ed03d00b/6494690e-1d5f-418d-adca-0ac515b7b742/api/mydatabase/");
            //return promise as durandal seems to want...
            return service.then(function (db) {
                vm.set("airports", db.Airport.asKendoDataSource());
            });

        };



        var deactivate = function () {
        };

        var viewAttached = function (view) {
            //kendo.init($("#airportGrid"));
            //kendo.bind(view, vm);
            //kendo.bind($("#airportGrid"), vm);
        };

        var vm = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
            activate: activate,
            deactivate: deactivate,
            airports: [],
            title: 'Airports',
            viewAttached: viewAttached
        });

        return vm;
    });
```

Durandal view:

```
<section>
    <h2 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h2>
    <div id="airportGrid" data-kendo-role="grid" data-kendo-sortable="true" data-kendo-pageable="true" data-kendo-page-size="25" data-kendo-editable="true" data-kendo-columns='["id", "Abbrev", "Name"]' data-kendo-bind="source: airports"></div>    
</section>
```

I see the call being made to jaystack in Chrome's network monitor:
[https://open.jaystack.net/c72e6c4b-27ba-49bb-9321-e167ed03d00b/6494690e-1d5f-418d-adca-0ac515b7b742/api/mydatabase//Airport?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=25](https://open.jaystack.net/c72e6c4b-27ba-49bb-9321-e167ed03d00b/6494690e-1d5f-418d-adca-0ac515b7b742/api/mydatabase//Airport?%24inlinecount=allpages&%24top=25)
And I see data coming back.

The kendoui grid is created nicely but there is no data in it (I think this means kendoui is happy and the MVVM bindings are being bound to, however the created kendoui grid doesn't seem to want to understand the kendoui datasource created from jaydata)

Without durandal this works just nicely as demonstrated in:
http://jsfiddle.net/t316/4n62B/29/

I have been trying and trying for 2 days now - can someone please help me out?

Thanks
TJ

Comment: Interesting use case... and pretty specific. Assuming you're running Durandal 1.2 can you reproduce what you got so far using https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2.

Comment: @RainerAtSpirit I forked and uploaded the files I thought were needed, but I am new to durandal and couldn't get it running yet. Maybe you can take a look? http://tolgaerdogus.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/.  And yes - I updated the hottowel template to use durandal 1.2 through nuget.

Comment: http://tolgaerdogus.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/ gives error in ff and Chrome and makes no request to JayStrom at all...
In Chrom: Uncaught ReferenceError: viewModelBinder is not defined main.js:20

Comment: Finally got the dfiddle working and it demonstrates my issue: http://tolgaerdogus.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/#/airports

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like everything is working now after removing the parts that are only required by breeze.

Nevertheless I'd suggest restructuring the working [dFiddle code](https://github.com/tolgaerdogus/dFiddle-1.2/blob/gh-pages/App/samples/airports.js) slightly to ensure that a) `vm` is defined before setting `vm.airports` in `activate` and b) there's no need to create a dummy `vm.airports` `kendo.data.DataSource()` that gets overwritten in `activate` anyway.

```
define(function( ) {

    var vm = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
      activate: activate,
      deactivate: deactivate,
      // airports: new kendo.data.DataSource(),
      title: 'Airports',
      viewAttached: viewAttached
    });

    return vm;

    function activate () {
      var service = $data.initService("https://open.jaystack.net/c72e6c4b-27ba-49bb-9321-e167ed03d00b/6494690e-1d5f-418d-adca-0ac515b7b742/api/mydatabase/");
      return service.then(function( db ) {
          vm.airports = db.Airport.asKendoDataSource();
      });

    }

    function deactivate () {
    }

    function viewAttached ( view ) {
      //kendo.init($("#airportGrid"));
      //kendo.bind(view, vm);
      //kendo.bind($("#airportGrid"), vm);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version on jQuery do you use? Try with 1.8.3 or 1.9 + Migration.
In Chrome switch the stop sign to purple (two clicks) to catch uncaught exceptions and see if there is any.

Comment: I switched my project to 1.8.3 and the problem is still there.  You can see it for yourself now at: http://tolgaerdogus.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/#/airports

Comment: Hmm - well changing line https://github.com/tolgaerdogus/dFiddle-1.2/blob/gh-pages/App/samples/airports.js#L8 from db.Airport.asKendoDataSource(vm.airports); to vm.airports = db.Airport.asKendoDataSource(); seems to fix the problem on dfiddle but not my local hottowel project.  This led me to the culprit: jaydatamodules/qDeferred.js.  I was including that and now that I have switched to not including it (emulating dfiddle) it has started to work for me. Any ideas on why this is the case?

Comment: actually it was my first guess but then I removed it from my answer :) JayData can use q promise or jQuery promise, whichever is available. Durandal uses jQuery. Breeze can only use q promise. I guess you left the patch in durandal which enables durandaljs to support q promise to support breeze and that causes confusion.